# Testing a custom React hook that shows an exit prompt

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, react-hooks

I have inherited some TypeScript React code that includes a custom React hook to display a prompt when a user reloads or exits a page when there are edits on the page.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const initBeforeUnload = (showExitPrompt: boolean) => {
  window.onbeforeunload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
    if (showExitPrompt) {
      const e = event || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e) {
        e.returnValue = '';
      }
      return '';
    }
  };
};

// Hook
const useExitPrompt = (
  bool: boolean
): [boolean, (showPrompt: boolean) => void] => {
  const [showExitPrompt, setShowExitPrompt] = useState<boolean>(bool);

  window.onload = () => {
    initBeforeUnload(showExitPrompt);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initBeforeUnload(showExitPrompt);
  }, [showExitPrompt]);

  useEffect(() => () => {
    initBeforeUnload(false);
  }, []);

  return [showExitPrompt, setShowExitPrompt];
};

export default useExitPrompt;
```

No unit tests were included with this code when I inherited it, so I'm writing tests now. So far I've come up with the following:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import useExitPrompt from './useExitPrompt';

describe('useExitPrompt', () => {
  it('should update the value of showExitPrompt', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(({ usePrompt }) => useExitPrompt(usePrompt),
      {
        initialProps: {
          usePrompt: true
        }
      });

    const [initialShowExitPrompt, setShowExitPrompt] = result.current;
    expect(initialShowExitPrompt).toBe(true);

    act(() => {
      setShowExitPrompt(false);
    });

    const [updatedShowExitPrompt] = result.current;
    expect(updatedShowExitPrompt).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

This test passes, but it doesn't really get to the meat of what the hook is about: when `showExitPrompt` is true and the page is unloaded, is the exit prompt displayed? (In fact, it really only tests that the `useState` hook works, which is not what I want at all.) Unfortunately, I've run into a brick wall in trying to figure out how to test this; any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a way would be to manually trigger the `beforeunload` event([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68773090/9632621)) + using `jest.fn()` or something like that as the event listener for `window.onbeforeunload`.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thanks for the suggestion. The problem I'm running into there is that since `window.onbeforeunload` is being assigned as part of the code (in the `initBeforeUnload` function), mocking it doesn't work. The mock just gets replaced by the actual coded value when I call `renderHook`.  I could define the mock after calling `renderHook`, but it seems to me that mocking that function then causes the exit prompt not to be displayed. Since that's what I'm trying to test for, it seems counterproductive to me. Or perhaps I have misunderstood your suggestion...

Comment: I see. Maybe the manually dispatched event could have its `preventDefault()` method spied by jest? Something among these lines: `mockedFn = jest.fn(); e = new Event("beforeunload"); e.preventDefault = mockedFn; dispatchEvent(e)` and then check that `mockedFn` has been called.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Good idea, thanks! That at least confirms that the function is running even if it doesn't technically confirm that a prompt was triggered.

Comment: I think during testing all you can do is to simulate stuff and AFAIK jest uses [jsom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) under the hood. So, if that function is invoked, in a real environment such event would actually be triggered.